# How can I combine multiple groups of PDFs using the command line?

Tags: terminal, command-line, pdf, macos

I have 1000 groups of 5 pdf files I need to combine/merge. I aware of the "/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py" command and have created the 1000 different versions of the command I need. Currently I am copying and pasting each separate line into Terminal to run it. Is there a way to put all 1000 lines into a script and run the script.
Thanks

Comment: Can you add a few samples of your code to the question?

Comment: Also, how can the five files to be merged be identified? Do they have specific names, are in a specific directory, or something else?

Comment: @patrix All the files are in the one directory, they have specific names and a unique merge file name, there are actually more than 5 files as you will see from the lines below.

Comment: @patrix   "/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py"  -o 71290-Leung-HeiTung-Bernice_5-2-2017.pdf Leung-HeiTung-Bernice_5B-aaY5B-EDITED.pdf Leung-HeiTung-Bernice_5B-ART5BFINAL.pdf Leung-HeiTung-Bernice_5B-CE5Bfinal.pdf Leung-HeiTung-Bernice_5B-DRY5B-FINAL.pdf Leung-HeiTung-Bernice_5B-FRYR5BFINAL.pdf Leung-HeiTung-Bernice_5B-LIB5B.pdf Leung-HeiTung-Bernice_5B-MUY5BEdited2017.pdf Leung-HeiTung-Bernice_5B-PE5BFinal.pdf

Not enough characters to add another line, but they all have the same format.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information, it‘s too hard to read as a comment. Also, how do names of which belong together differ from names who don‘t? Any programmatic solution will need to follow some rules to combine the right files

Comment: @patrix We have a misunderstanding. The files are school reports, using a spreadsheet and some lookups, concatenate and a little vba I have already sorted and produced each line of code. Copying and pasting the long line above into Terminal produces the correct file. What I want to do is not have to copy and paste each line separately but put all lines in one file and run it. So if i simplify the long line above to "Join.pf" -o mergefile1 file1 file2 file3 etc I want to add it and the next 999 lines like it to a script to run in Terminal. Don't know how.

Comment: There is no mention of a spreadsheet or anything in your question, so maybe you could add some more details about that?

Comment: And basically, you probably can just copy/paste all lines at once to have Terminal run them.

Comment: Thanks @patrix, I have been copying and pasting and its working OK.

Answer (score 5):

The functionality to combine PDFs is built into Preview.app, and this can be a handy approach for dealing with small numbers of documents.

Recent versions of macOS also have a Python script that automates this process for multiple PDF files. This script is located at:

`/System/Library/Automator/Combine\ PDF\ Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py`

You can run the script directly in Terminal, but it might be handy to add an alias in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```bash
alias combinepdfs='/System/Library/Automator/Combine\ PDF\ Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py'
```

Instead of typing the long location to the script every time, now you can run this script using a single command! (Don't forget to reload after making changes: `source ~/.bash_profile`.)

---

Say I have a directory of lecture notes `~/Documents/Lectures` that contains the following files:

```
lec2.pdf  lec3.pdf  lec4.pdf  lec5.pdf  lec6.pdf  lec7.pdf  lec8.pdf  lec9.pdf lec10.pdf lec11.pdf lec12.pdf lec13.pdf lec14.pdf lec15.pdf lec16.pdf lec17.pdf
```

I can **combine these PDF files** using the following command:

```bash
$ combinepdfs -o lec-combined.pdf lec{2..17}.pdf
```

The general usage pattern is listed in the help command:

```
$ combinepdfs --help

Usage: join [--output <file>] [--shuffle] [--verbose]
```

---

There is also an extra feature to shuffle pages:

```
--shuffle
#       Take a page from each PDF input file in turn before taking another from each file.
#       If this option is not specified then all of the pages from a PDF file are appended
#       to the output PDF file before the next input PDF file is processed.
```

Answer (score 0):

For macOS Sonoma, use `…/Contents/MacOS/join` since `…/Contents/Resources/join.py` is no longer provided.

```sh
alias combine-pdf-pages='/System/Library/Automator/Combine\ PDF\ Pages.action/Contents/MacOS/join'

combine-pdf-pages -o output.pdf in001.pdf in002.pdf
```

---

Also, at WWDC 2021, Apple announced a migration from `automator` to `shortcuts` on macOS.

> “This is just the start of a multi-year transition Automator will continue to be supported, and *you can import Automator workflows into beginning one with Shortcuts*,” Federighi said.

[Use Automator workflows with the Shortcuts app on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/use-your-workflows-with-shortcuts-autc12e3fb97/mac)

> You can import Automator workflows into the Shortcuts app on your Mac. Shortcuts can convert most Automator workflows into shortcuts that carry out the same functions, events, and automations—you simply drag a workflow file into Shortcuts and the conversion happens automatically.

[Run shortcuts from the command line](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts-mac/run-shortcuts-from-the-command-line-apd455c82f02/mac)

```sh
man shortcuts

# NAME
#      shortcuts – Command-line utility for running shortcuts.
# 
# SYNOPSIS
#      shortcuts run shortcut-name-or-identifier [--input-path input-path ...]
#                [--output-path output-path ...] [--output-type output-type]
#      … more …
# 
# DESCRIPTION
#      The shortcuts command is used to run, list, view 
#      or sign shortcuts. To create or edit a shortcut, 
#      use the Shortcuts application.
# 
# OPTIONS
#    shortcuts run
#      shortcut-name-or-identifier
#      … more …
```